# Dynamically modifying the page without using browser extensions

Tags: javascript, php, html, firefox

Our upstream provider recently changed the interface at their portal we use to collect order information. The page that displays order details used to display item IDs. These IDs are critical for our workflow and now they are hidden, but they still can be retrieved if inspecting the page code in the browser.

I wonder if there is a way to make and install a script in Firefox, that would retrieve the ID of the item from the page code and display it in the pop-up upon hovering over the item in the list.
I heard that browsers block custom code injection, so I have doubts whether my idea even viable without creating a browser extension.

But if it *is* possible, I'd like to know what would be the right approach. Should this be done with javascript?

Comment: Why using a browser extension is not an option?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski we have quite a few extensions installed already, and I'd rather not bother people with making them install another one for such a, seemingly, small change in functionality. Since we use a custom CSS stylesheet in Firefox, I thought adding a script would be a more elegant solution. But if it's easier to achieve that with an extension, I am down.

Comment: `adding a script` is exactly what an extension does

Comment: Turns out the solution that worked best for us is importing the scripts into Tampermonkey.